# How to open p:dialog inside a js file?

Tags: primefaces

I want to open a p:dialog in a js file. My code is below:
`<h:outputScript name="js/check.js"/> 
<p:dialog id="dialog1"  widgetVar="ex" >
</p:dialog>`

In the js file I have written a function and inside that I have tried  `ex.show();` but it says ex is undefined. 
Similarly I also want to invoke a `p:commandButton`  in that file and I tried 
`document.getElementById("hformid:commandbuttonid").click();` and it says
`document.getElementById("hformid:commandbuttonid")` is null. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

May be 'ex' is defined after your 'check.js' script is executed. Assuming your are using JQuery, try something like

```
$(document).ready ( function() {
    ex.show();
});
```

So 'ex.show();' will be executed after the whole page is parsed.